# How to change the selected date text color in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code of creating `DataPicker` programatically. I need to change the selected date text color to pink. But it is black by default. i used the below code but not working. I referred few links but not working. Thanks in advance 
[How to change the datepicker current date text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736668/how-to-change-the-datepicker-current-date-text-color)

```
self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
textField.inputView = self.datePicker
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900632/how-do-i-change-the-text-color-of-uipickerview-with-multiple-components-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

`dobDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
dobDatePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")`

Answer (score 1):

> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable. You should
>   integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout. Although date
>   pickers can be resized, they should be used at their intrinsic content
>   size.[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker)

If you want to  customised datepicker. you can use **UIPickerView**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")

Comment: FYI - this is an undocumented, private API that could stop working or even cause a crash in any future iOS update.

Comment: Why was this chosen as the accepted answer when it simply replicates the code already being used in the question? If this is the correct answer, why was the question even asked?