# How to change selected date color of UIDatePicker programmatically - Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift4, uidatepicker

I have created `UIDatePicker` programatically and added to `UITableViewCell`. Everything works fine but date color not getting changed even after apply `tintColor`.

My implementation is:

```
   var startDatePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    datePicker.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
    datePicker.isHidden = true
    datePicker.tintColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.tag = 0
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return datePicker
}()
```

I want to show in **white color** but its showing in default **black** **color**. Refer screenshot also.

[image]

Comment: Why have you edited the tag to swift3 when the question clearly mentions swift4? @anbu.karthik?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, I found the way to do by using private API KVC itself ([ViruMax's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50808820/1023074) ans):

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

But I observed, If we implement UIDatePicker using **closure** then above API must have to assign both closure instance of UIDatePicker as well as outer instance of UIDatePicker. Then only its working.

e.g Outer instance of `UIDatePicker` (startDatePicker) also need to set below KVC.

```
startDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

Ans yes it works for Swift 4.

Refer updated screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817917/2764966) answer.

Apple Documentation says:

> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable. You should
>   integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout. Although date
>   pickers can be resized, they should be used at their intrinsic content
>   size. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker)

But then also if you want to customize text color, there is a way to achieve this using private API as below:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

however, private API that could stop working or even cause a crash in any future iOS update.

Then the stable solution would be creating your own Date Picker using `UIPickerView` and while using that you can customize text color like:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: pickerData[row], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])
    return attributedString
}
```